# [PHP-MYSQL]Query for Reporting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, report

I need help to deliver this to my client. He insisted that the format of the inventory report should be like this:

[image: Report]

While my inventory table in mysql is like this:

[image: Inventory Table]

Basically he wants the application to group the inventory by item name and color then for the quantity column he want the application to show it in one column containing the size printed depend on how much the quantity is. So if the inventory table says we have 4 red nike shoes size 42 and 3 red nike shoes size 41 then it will be printed " 41 41 41 42 42 42 42" in this column.

I hope i explained it well,please see my inventory table and the report above for detail.

I need advise on how to do this properly, can i do this using only sql query or should i combine it with php code as well?

Thanks for the help

Warm Regards

Comment: Well I think your "client" is confused. But the customer is never wrong. Well if I said to try it using both sql and php would that get you going. You've basically psuedo coded it in your description. Don't try to be too clever too soon and break it down and see what comes out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to first use the query:

```
select Item,Color,GROUP_CONCAT(Size) as SIZE,GROUP_CONCAT(Qty) as Qty from --tablename-- group by Item,Color
```

**Then use php while loop to get your result**

```
while($num=$result){
$item=$num['Item'];
$Color=$num['Color'];
$size=explode(",",$num['SIZE']);
$size_show="";
$qty=$num['Qty'];
$qty1=explode(",",$qty);
foreach($size as $key=>$val){
$qty2=$qty1[$val];
$k=1;
while($k<=$qty2){
$size_show.="".$val." ";
$k++;
}

}

echo $size_show;
}
```

**Please note that i have given only the idea, and have not tested the code**

Comment: thanks a lot  i've tried your idea and applied it in my code. It works and i just do a slight modification in the for each loop: foreach($size as $key=>$val)
  {
   $qty2=$qty1[$key];
   $k=1;
   while($k<=$qty2)
   {
    $size_show.="".$val." ";
    $k++;
   }

  }

Comment: I u feel it is correct you can voteup and click on the right button

Comment: yup, i've done that but since my reputation is still less than 15 i think it won't be published